# Clone or Copy rows in same table

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ to SQL, I have a table named "tblCourse" I want to select some rows from this table based on some criteria and then insert these selected rows as new records in the same table. Can any body suggest some post, link or direction?

```
public IQueryable<tblCourseNeededHours> CloneAllCourseNeededHoursInDepartmentInSemester(int departmentId, string semester)
{
return from allCourses in _db.tblCourseNeededHours orderby allCourses.tblCourse.CourseName
where allCourses.tblCourse.tblInstitute.DepartmentID == departmentId && allCourses.Semester
== semester select allCourses;

var thisTable = from t in _db.tblCourseNeededHours where
t.tblCourse.tblInstitute.DepartmentID == departmentId && t.Semester == semester

//select everything except ID
select _db.tblCourseNeededHours {  Semester = ?, NeedHoursPerWeek = ?, AssignToInstitute=? 
(I want it null for new record), Freezed=? (I want it null for new record)    
}; 
_db.tblCourseNeededHours.InsertAllOnsubmit(thisTable);
_db.SubmitChanges();
```

Now when i use

```
select _db.tblCourseNeededHours {  Semester = ?, NeedHoursPerWeek = ?, AssignToInstitute=? (I want it null), Freezed=? (I want it null)    
};
```

? mention that "what should i put here and i am having error here, also on this line

```
_db.tblCourseNeededHours.InsertAllOnsubmit(thisTable);
```

Comment: you dont have a primary key in your table? because if you do, you will get primary key constraint violation. If you have auto number as primary key, then you can insert same records with a bit of manipulation, What is your exact table structure and what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting, but I'm afraid I lost something along the way. Can you please check the contents - and the formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your db schema, But something like this should work for you.

```
var oldItems= (from p on db.tblCourses where p.InstructorId=43 select p).ToList();
if(oldItems!=null)
{
  foreach(var item in oldItems)
  {
    tblCourse objNew=new tblCourse();
    objNew.Instructor="John";  
   // update someproperty values from old row if you need        
    objNew.Credits=item.Credits+2;
    db.tblCourses.Add(objNew);
  }
  db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Assuming db is your datacontext

Comment: He is trying to insert multiple rows.

Comment: I have primaryKey as autoIncrement Field, tblCourse(CourseID(pk),CourseName,NeedHours) and yes my db is datacontext

Comment: @habib.osu: Yea. I just gave a generic idea to him. Now updated my answer.